# Put data in my-account/view-order/id/ page

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic, actions, order

Is ther a filter or an action to put information after order status information just before "Order Details" title?

I found 'woocommerce_view_order' action, but it puts all at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'before_woocommerce_order_details', 5 );
function before_woocommerce_order_details($order_id){
  $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  echo "Order Status : ".$order->get_status();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that if a call this action from plugin it puts everything in the right position. I f a call it from function.php it puts all at the bottom...